# Select Connected Bones in Pose Mode

Tags: armature, 3d-view

I want to select all bones of the left Hand without having to click or box select each individual bone.

[image]

Quote from: http://blender-manual-i18n.readthedocs.io/ja/latest/rigging/armatures/selecting.html

> You can select at once all the bones in the chain which the active
>   (last selected) bone belongs to by using the linked selection tool,
>   L.

Doesn't seem to work for me. Ctr+L does nothing, L only selects bones directly under the mouse pointer, no matter what bone chain it belongs to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is difficult to diagnose this without the Blender file. One issue could be that although the bones are parented to one another, they are not "connected". To correct this, go into edit mode, and make sure that "connected" is enabled for the bones:
[image]

Using L will select all bones that are connected though, which may include the entire rig, not just the hand, depending on your setup.

Alternatively, you should consider using Bone Groups for making such selections: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/armatures/properties/bone_groups.html

Comment: Where is the keybind for L in the UserPreferences? I have overriden some settings there..

Comment: No idea off the top of my head. Search for "Select Linked" under pose mode.

Comment: Found it under pose "select_linked". Changed L to Shift+L, works now thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Though this isn't perfect, you could Select Hierarchy with the <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd> keys. <kbd>[</kbd> will select the parent of the selected bone, and <kbd>]</kbd> will select the *first* child.

To select the hand, you can manually select the first bone of each finger, then extend the selection to the entire hand with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>.